# How do I convert json to different format using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am new to jq. Want to convert one json to different format using jq

Need suggestion how to achieve.

Input JSON

```
{
"key": {
    "type": [
      "object",
      {
        "A": "string",
        "B": "string"
      }
    ],
    "value": {
      "A": "value of A",
      "B": "value of B"
    }
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "A": {
        "value": "value of A"
    },
    "B": {
        "value": "value of B"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Given the input as shown, the following jq program produces the required output, though the problem statement is open to many interpretations:

```
.key.value | map_values({value: .})
```

Comment: I have used ```jq '. | split(",") | map( split(":") | {value: .[0]} ) | {"A": .} ' -R -s```